# Unable to login to root shell of Linux system built using Buildroot

Tags: systemd, login, buildroot

I built Linux kernel and root file system using Buildroot(2022.08.x) for STM32MP157 target. SystemD is chosen as init system. The target boots and login prompt appear but I am unable to login to shell.

I tried the user name as 'root' and password as 'root' but the system complain stating that 'login: can't set groups:' as shown in below.

```
[  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[  OK  ] Reached target Socket Units.
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
[  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
         Starting Dropbear SSH daemon...
[  OK  ] Started Serial Getty on ttySTM0.
[  OK  ] Reached target Login Prompts.
[  OK  ] Started Dropbear SSH daemon.
[  OK  ] Reached target Multi-User System.

Welcome to Buildroot
buildroot login: root
Password: 
login: can't set groups: 
Welcome to Buildroot
buildroot login:
```

Does any one know what could be the root cause and how to fix this?

Comment: I see that SSH Dropbear is running? Do you get the same error logging in via SSH?

Comment: Hi @eyoung100 , With Dropbear I can SSH to target and login to shell but can't get root access.